# Request return null mobile number

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman, httprequest

i have code running in Postman but when i try in c# it is not run and return error 801 which means mobile number null, however it is not null and same running working fine in Postman: i run from localhost, and this code will be run from desktop application

My Code:

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        
        var postData = "username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&sender= salon&language=1&Mobile=000000000&message=test4444";              
        
            
        string Url = "https://smsmisr.com/api/webapi/?";
        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
        
        

        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        
        
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/jsonn";
        //myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

        this.Label16.Text = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        
        myStreamReader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();

        myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried exporting the code in  postman to c#? I was surprised by a recent question that the user did not know about this feature. Similar issue. Just try to generate a c# code snippet on postman and give that a go.

Comment: You are posting with content-type `application/jsonn` (that should probably be `application/json`. Yet you are posting your data as a query string. 

Furthermore in your query string you have `&sender= salon`. I'm not sure about that space there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your content type is a json but you are passing a query string as payload. Why not tying this payload?

```
{
  "username": "xxxxx",
  "password": "xxxxx",
  "sender": "salon",
  "language": 1,
  "Mobile": "000000000",
  "message": "test4444"
}
```